# Same parenthesis for nameprefix and first initial

Tags: biblatex

I would like to have in the same parenthesis, the first initial of the author and its prefix.

For example :

Chazelles (Cl.-A. de) etc. but for the moment I have :

Chazelles (Cl.-A.) (de) ...

with this code

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\parentext{#1}}                   
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\parentext{#1}}

@INPROCEEDINGS{chazellesroux10,
  author = {{\relax Cl}aire-Anne de Chazelles and Jean-{\relax Cl}aude Roux},
  title = {La construction en terre crue en France méditerranéenne},
  booktitle = {Archéologie des rivages méditerranéens: 50 ans de recherche},
  pages = {343-349},
}
```

Do you have any idea? I don't know if is possible.

And thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT :** Oh wonderful !
It's almost perfect but now, for inbook, inproceedings etc. the firstname is not in parenthesis. I guess, we need to change another macro like byeditor, but how ?

My MWE is particularly long but there is a lot of change because of the recommendations of my director.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}                                                       %type de document+ police
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.75]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}




\usepackage{microtype}  %gère la microtypo
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

%%% MARGES ET INTERLIGNES
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper}
    \geometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm , right=2cm}

                                    %gestion interligne                                                     
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing                                                                                         % interligne 1.5
\let\oldquotation\quotation                                                                     %Rédéfinit l'environnement quotation pour avoir un interligne de 1
\let\endoldquotation\endquotation
\renewenvironment{quotation}
{\begin{oldquotation}\singlespace}
 {\end{oldquotation}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %BILIOGRAPHIE  
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[                                                                                                                %BILIOGRAPHIE
  backend=bibtex,
  language=french,
  style=authoryear,
  firstinits,
  mergedate=false,
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  maxcitenames=2,
   maxbibnames=999
]{biblatex} 

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}                %tiret après le label
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                          rajoute date

%enlève guillement article et in
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1} 
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace\addcolon\space}}

  %Met les abréviations des revues
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {}
        {%
          \printtext[journaltitle]
            {%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
              \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
             }%
         }%
    }
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
}


%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extraalpha}}
\makeatother



% "Et al." en ITALIQUE

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

 %%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{##1}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother
    %minuscule citation
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}                 
%Enlève parenthèse colloque
\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{                        
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {%
      \bibstring{presentedat}%
      \printfield{eventtitle}%
    }%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext{%
       \printfield{venue}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printeventdate}}%
  \newunit
}

    %modification des chaines de langues
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
 byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%                         
 {Établit\space par}%
{dir\adddotspace\smartof}, 
in = {\textit{in}},%
 editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
 editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
 opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
idem = {\emph{idem}},%
ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
%pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
 %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}

%modifie les pages des articles ... par pp. au lieu de p.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%


%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
    \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
%     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother


 %modifié book pour virgule
 \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma         % ajout de la virgule
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  %Change ordre des entrées pour les in quelquechoses : 
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
 \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{proceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma% ajout de la virgule
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


%% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \ifnameundef{namea}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
          \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother

  %gère les parenthèses pour les particules
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibparens{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}\isdot}}% added \mkbibparens
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}% added \bibopenparen
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}% added \ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\bibcloseparen}}}% this line is new



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FICHIER BIBLIO
\addbibresource{master01,alire}


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Présentation biblio %%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document} 


\nocite{*}

\begin{spacing}{1}


\printbibliography[keyword=source,title=Les sources primaires]

\printbibliography[notkeyword=source]

 \end{spacing}



\end{document}
```

[image]

I can not integrate my bibliography with filecontent. Sorry.

And I would like in : dir de DELESTRE (X), MERCHESI (H) like author.
I also have another problem with it but I think I'll make a new topic as ideally I wish have:
in : DELESTRE (X), MERCHESI (H) dir. ...

Comment: Don't you think `Chazelles de (Cl.-A.)` would be better-looking? I don't know if it's easier than what you require, though.

Comment: Could you provide an example for the preoblem with `@inbook`, `@inproceedings`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you posted is not an MWE in the sense that it is not a code that will compile to a full document. Please post a document that starts with `\documentclass` and has `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in it (ideally it should also contain the bib entry for "Chazelles, Roux 2010".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not overly easy. Instead of manipulating `\mkbibnamefirst` and `\mkbibnameprefix`, we have to manipulate the `name:last-first` macro directly.

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibparens{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\bibcloseparen}}}
```

In case `useprefix` is turned on we just wrap the first name in parentheses via `\mkbibparens{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}`.

If `useprefix` is false we print an open parenthesis before the first name (`\bibopenparen\mkbibnamefirst{#2}`); the parenthesis before the name prefix is only printed if there was no first name (that means only if one has not been printed already;`\ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}`); if either of the first name or prefix field contained anything, a closing parenthesis is printed.

In the MWE below we also use `\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibparens{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}\isdot}}% added \mkbibparens
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}% added \bibopenparen
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}% added \ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\bibcloseparen}}}% this line is new

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{chazellesroux10,
  author = {Claire-Anne de Chazelles and Jean-Claude Roux},
  title = {La construction en terre crue en France méditerranéenne},
  booktitle = {Archéologie des rivages méditerranéens: 50 ans de recherche},
  pages = {343-349},
}
@book{Goethe:Faust1, 
  title   = {Faust},
  subtitle= {Eine Tragödie},
  author  = {von Goethe},
  year    = {1808},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{chazellesroux10,wilde,cicero,Goethe:Faust1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]