# Problem with update biblatex

Tags: biblatex, french

Recently I reinstalled Windows 10 on my computer, so I reinstalled texlive, texstudio, etc.

I had a bibliography style which was perfect thanks to this forum but yesterday when I compiled, I discovered with horror that my bibliography style had changed.

Indeed, as you can see with pictures, there are not bracket for authors and byeditor's initial, besides citation style and the label are in small caps whereas I would like in lower case. I don't understand why it's changing.

Before update and with my last configuration I had:
[image: Before]
Now I have that:
[image: Now]

And to success to compile I have to replace firstinit by giveninits

Do you have an idea? I guess it's cause to update of biblatex but I'm a too bad in code to know where the issue is ?

Thanks,
PS: sorry for my big MWE ...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{csquotes} 

%MACRO

\providecommand{\ier}{\textsuperscript{er}}
\providecommand{\iers}{\textsuperscript{ers}}
\providecommand{\iere}{\textsuperscript{ère}}
\providecommand{\ieres}{\textsuperscript{ères}}
\providecommand{\ieme}{\textsuperscript{e}}
\providecommand{\iemes}{\textsuperscript{es}}
\providecommand{\nd}{\textsuperscript{nd}}
\providecommand{\nds}{\textsuperscript{nds}}
\providecommand{\nde}{\textsuperscript{nde}}
\providecommand{\ndes}{\textsuperscript{ndes}}
\providecommand{\no}{\textsuperscript{o}}
\providecommand{\nos}{\textsuperscript{os}}
\providecommand{\mme}{M\textsuperscript{me}\space}
\providecommand{\mmes}{M\textsuperscript{mes}\space}
\providecommand{\mr}{M.\space}
\providecommand{\mrs}{MM.\space}

%bibliography
  \usepackage[%                                                             
  backend=bibtex,%
  style=authoryear,%
  autolang=hyphen,%
  giveninits,%
  mergedate=false,%
  style=authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2,%
  maxbibnames=999% 
  ]{biblatex} 
  \addbibresource{bibliographie/fusion}

  \renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
  \DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

  \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}                  %tiret après le label
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                            rajoute date

  \DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1} 
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 enlève guillemets articles
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printdate%
    \newunit}

  \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %enlève le p. automatique pour le postnote dans les citations

  \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}


  %Met les abréviations des revues
  \renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
    \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {%
        \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {}
        {%
            \printtext[journaltitle]
            {%
                \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
                \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
                \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
  }


  %Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
  %
  \makeatletter
  \AtEveryBibitem{%
    \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
    \clearfield{extraalpha}}
  \makeatother



  % "Et al." en ITALIQUE
  \renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
        and
        test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
        \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

  %%% Histoire des noms    et al...
  \makeatletter
  \renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{##1}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
    \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
  \makeatother

  %minuscule citation
  \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}   

  %Enlève parenthèse colloque

  \renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{                        
    \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {%
        \bibstring{presentedat}%
        \printfield{eventtitle}%
    }%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
    }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printtext{%
            \printfield{venue}%
            \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
            \printeventdate}}%
    \newunit
  }


  \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
    byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%                      
    {Établit\space par}%
    {dir\adddotspace\smartof}, 
    in = {\textit{in}},%                                    %et en italique
    editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
    editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
    opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
    idem = {\emph{idem}},%
    byeditor = {dir\adddot},% Remplace sous la direction de pour les improceedings etc. 
    ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
    %pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
    %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
  }

  %modifie les pages des articles ... par pp. au lieu de p.
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%


  %enlève la virugule avant dir.
  \makeatletter
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseeditor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {\bibnamedash}
        {\printnames{editor}%
            %   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
            \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
            \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
        %     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
        \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
        \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
  \makeatother


  % put (dir.) at the end (byeditor)  pour tout ce qui est in : auteur dir.
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%%%\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}       %%%% suppress
        \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
        \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        % \addspace                                  %%%% suppress
        %     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}          %%%% 
        \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}             %%%% 
        \clearname{editor}%            %%%%%%%%% 
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}



  %%modifié book pour virgule
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\addcomma
    \printfield{pagetotal}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%     rajoute a la fin series + nomber pour avoir la collection a la fin de la ligne. La modification du style est plus bas.
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
        \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  %Change ordre des entrées pour les in quelquechoses : 
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
    \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit\newblock   
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
        \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
    \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit\newblock   
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins 
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printlist{organization}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    %  \newunit\newblock %%%% enlever
    \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
        \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
    \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit\newblock   
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
        \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{proceedings}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printlist{organization}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\addcomma
    \printfield{pagetotal}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}% rajoute collection
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
        \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}


  %% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea
  \makeatletter
  \renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseauthor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {\bibnamedash}
        {\printnames{author}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
            \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
            \ifnameundef{namea}
            {}
            {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
                \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
                \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
  \newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
    \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
  \makeatother


  %met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
  \renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
            \printtext{}%
            \printfield{series}%
            \setunit*{\space}%
            \printfield{number}%
            \printtext{}}%
    }} %%% il y a un point en enleveant \nopunct.

    %Rajoute une virgule après le titre du journal et avant le numéro du volume     
    \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
        \usebibmacro{journal}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \iffieldundef{series}
        {}
        {\newunit
            \printfield{series}%
            \setunit{\addspace}}%
        \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
        \usebibmacro{issue}%
        \newunit}

    %Permet d'enlever le tiret après in si pas d'auteur.
    \renewbibmacro{in:}{%
        \ifentrytype{article}
        {}
        {\printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
            \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}


    %permet de mettre les initiales entre parenthèses et surtout les particules nobilaires
    \renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}

    \renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
        \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
            \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
            \ifblank{#3}{}{%
                \ifcapital
                {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
                {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
                \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
            \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
            \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
            \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibparens{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}\isdot}}% added \mkbibparens
        {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
            \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
            \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
            \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
            \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
            \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}% added \bibopenparen
            \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}% added \ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}
            \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\bibcloseparen}}}% this line is new
    %%%


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{arnaud2005,
    title =     {Les routes de la navigation antique. Itinéraires en Méditerranée},
    publisher = {Errance},
    year =      {2005},
    author =    {Pascal Arnaud},
    pagetotal = {248},
    address =   {Paris},
}

@Inproceedings{arcelin1976,
    author =    {Patrice Arcelin},
    title =     {Les civilisations de l'âge du Fer en Provence},
    booktitle = {La préhistoire française, II. Les civilisations néolithiques et protohistoriques de la France},
    year =      {1976},
    pages =     {657-675},
    editor =    {Guilaine, Jean},
    address =   {Paris},
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document} 

    \cite{arnaud2005, arcelin1976}

    \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Edit 1:
I have just discovered a last problem which appears for certain cases, how it appears with you:

```
@Book{roman.roman1997,
  title =     {Histoire de la Gaule (VI\ieme{} s. av. J.-C. -- I\ier{} s. ap. J.-C.). Une confrontation culturelle},
  publisher = {Fayard},
  year =      {1997},
  author =    {Daniele Roman and Yves Roman},
  pagetotal = {791},
  address =   {Paris},
  owner =     {Axel},
}
```

This problem of initial appears in some other cases while my bibliography contains more than 500 entries which works well. Do you have an idea? I try to recreate entry, remove accent, change title etc. Nothing works !

[image: new problem... :(]

Comment: If your `biblatex` is not older than version 3.3, you need to adapt the name format, see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

Comment: Didn't check, but maybe it's enough to change `name:last-first` to `name:family-given`. All `\mkbibnamelast`s need to be `\mkbibnamefamily`, `\mkbibnamefisrt` becomes `\mkbibnamegiven` etc. pp.

Comment: I don't have this problem with your code: it compiles exactly as  before,  except I don't have `Ed. du CNRS`, which is not in your code (b.t.w.,  shouldn't it be  `Éd. du CNRS`?).

Comment: With initials between bracket ?! It's officially,I don't understand any more latex...

Comment: @moewe indeed my biblatex is version 3.3 so if I understand I have to modify some part of my code. I did what you say but it still does't work,  even it's worse :(

Comment: @Bernard I guess you have an older version of Biblatex/Biber, then?

Comment: Not at all: I have version 3.3 (MiKTeX, if that has any importance).

Comment: What's the best between try to change code for bibtex or use biber?

Comment: @Bernard That's very strange. I'm using TeX Live, but I wouldn't have thought that should matter. If I compile with XeTeX and BibTeX, I get nothing because the `.bib` file is, I'm assuming UTF-8 encoded for XeTeX and Biblatex issues a warning telling me I must use Biber. If I change the code to use Biber, then I get the erroneous output shown in the question rather than the target output. Moreover, as I understand it, this code is simply incompatible with the changes in 3.3 i.e. it *shouldn't* work.

Comment: @Axelito Use Biber.

Comment: @moewe `\bibnamedelimd` is supposed to insert a space, subject to penalty. Do you happen to know whether either where the space is added or the penalty has changed? I can [get rid of the space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303930/problem-with-update-biblatex/303993?noredirect=1#comment737419_303993) mentioned in this comment for testing purposes, but I'm not sure what the change is which causes the difference or how to modify the code appropriately.

Comment: @cfr Amongst the many changes in name handling in `biblatex` 3.3 is that the `name:family-given` macros have to be defined differently for Biber and BibTeX. With the BibTeX backend the name parts are strings and are tested with `\ifblank`, while with Biber they are macros and are tested with `\ifempty`. I suppose that is a problem here. The `\ifempty` macro had some other problems and so in the upcoming version 3.4 Biber will use `\ifdefvoid`. Using the "wrong" test can lead to unexpected output I guess. (I didn't have to check the case at hand, but I suspect that's what's going on.)

Comment: Of course above I wanted to say "I didn't have *time* to check the case at hand." Just did a bit of investigating and indeed, with the modified code below you don't get spurious space.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I couldn't actually get this to work with BibTeX at all. It refused to use that backend with a UTF-8 encoded `.bib`, which I guess would be preferable. I suppose the alternative would be for the OP to translate the entries and encoding to ASCII but that might cause its own problems ....

Comment: @cfr Yes if one uses XeLaTeX and has a French (and presumably UTF-8-encoded `.bib` file), Biber is definitely the way to go. But I could get the MWE to run (with BibTeX) if I removed the `\addbibresource{bibliographie/fusion}` line pointing to a non-existent (on my PC at least) file.

Comment: @moewe I got it to run that way, but I couldn't get a bibliography because I assumed the `.bib` should be UTF-8 encoded as it contains accented characters.

Comment: You get the initials so you can tell apart Daniele and Yves. Suppose one of them wrote a book with Smith. Then "Roman and Smith" would be ambiguous because we wouldn't know who it was. Check the uniquename and uniquelist features.

Comment: If you don't like it, you can use `uniquename=false,`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Biber you will need the following redefinition of `name:family-given`

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\bibcloseparen}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct\bibopenparen}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\bibcloseparen}}}
```

Aside from the changes already applied by cfr (those are also explained in [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)) we need to change the `\ifblank`s to `\ifdefvoid` (this is contrary to what you currently see in version 3.3, but `\ifempty` had some problems and will be removed).

Because name handling has changed so drastically, the old code and current BibTeX code needs to use `\ifblank`, while current Biber needs `\ifdefvoid`.

Comment: Thanks you very much !
I will keep two version of code to watch and learn ! 

To finish do you have an idea for the citation style's issue ? Why I have small caps when I do \parencite for example : I have (ARCELIN 1976) and I would like (Arcelin 1976).

I think that I make an excessive use of your kindness and yours talents

Comment: @Axelito Mhhh, did it not have small caps before? I'd have thought if we change all `\mkbibnamelast`s to `\mkbibnamefamily` everything should work. Try `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}`.

Comment: My hero ! I have no words (in english) to explain my gratitude ! :D

Comment: @moewe : thank you. What's the purpose of the `\ifboolexpe{%` (and following) lines exactly ?

Comment: @Carg That is a test that checks if both `#2` and `#3` are void (as checked by `\ifdefvoid`). That way we only print the closing braces if the name contained either given (first) name or prefix.

Comment: @moewe : ok ! and what's the difference with the previous syntax `\ifdefvoid{#2#3}{}` ?

Comment: @Carg I think the old version was `\ifempty{#2#3}`. In the old days the arguments were "strings", now they are macros. While two strings `#2` and `#3` are empty if their concatenation `#2#3` is empty, this doesn't work as easy with macros. `\ifdefvoid{\a\b}` doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, I have just seen that I have a problem with the author's prefix. The prefix appears to stick on names in capital in double. 
 For example I have : Chazelles 1992 : CHAZELLESDE (Cl.-A. de) ...
And I would like Chazelles 1992 : CHAZELLES (Cl.-A. de)

with this reference: @TechReport{chazelles1992,
 author =      {de Chazelles, {\relax Cl}aire-Anne},
 title =       {Montlaurès, Narbonne (Aude), Rapport de fouille triannuel 1990-1992},
 institution = {CNRS-UMR 154},
 year =        {1992},
}
PS: I don't know if I have to use comment or a do a new post. Sorry !

Comment: @Axelito Please check the updated version.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work. This uses Latin Modern since I doubt very much that I have a font called `Times New Roman` complete with small-caps etc.

I had to switch to the Biber backend to get this to work. Without that, Biblatex refused to countenance a UTF-8 encoded database file, which you presumably want in this case.

[image: modified example]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{arnaud2005,
  title =     {Les routes de la navigation antique. Itinéraires en Méditerranée},
  publisher = {Errance},
  year =      {2005},
  author =    {Pascal Arnaud},
  pagetotal = {248},
  address =   {Paris},
}
@Inproceedings{arcelin1976,
  author =    {Patrice Arcelin},
  title =     {Les civilisations de l'âge du Fer en Provence},
  booktitle = {La préhistoire française, II. Les civilisations néolithiques et protohistoriques de la France},
  year =      {1976},
  pages =     {657-675},
  editor =    {Guilaine, Jean},
  address =   {Paris},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\providecommand{\ier}{\textsuperscript{er}}
\providecommand{\iers}{\textsuperscript{ers}}
\providecommand{\iere}{\textsuperscript{ère}}
\providecommand{\ieres}{\textsuperscript{ères}}
\providecommand{\ieme}{\textsuperscript{e}}
\providecommand{\iemes}{\textsuperscript{es}}
\providecommand{\nd}{\textsuperscript{nd}}
\providecommand{\nds}{\textsuperscript{nds}}
\providecommand{\nde}{\textsuperscript{nde}}
\providecommand{\ndes}{\textsuperscript{ndes}}
\providecommand{\no}{\textsuperscript{o}}
\providecommand{\nos}{\textsuperscript{os}}
\providecommand{\mme}{M\textsuperscript{me}\space}
\providecommand{\mmes}{M\textsuperscript{mes}\space}
\providecommand{\mr}{M.\space}
\providecommand{\mrs}{MM.\space}

%bibliography
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
autolang=hyphen,
uniquename=init,
giveninits,
mergedate=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=999,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}                  %tiret après le label
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                            rajoute date

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 enlève guillemets articles
  \ifentrytype{article}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %enlève le p. automatique pour le postnote dans les citations

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

%Met les abréviations des revues
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
  {%
    \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {}
    {%
      \printtext[journaltitle]
      {%
        \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
      }%
    }%
  }
  {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
}

%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extraalpha}}
\makeatother

% "Et al." en ITALIQUE
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
  {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
    {\finalandcomma}
    {}%
    \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
  {}}

%%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{##1}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother

%minuscule citation
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}

%Enlève parenthèse colloque
\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
  {}
  {%
    \bibstring{presentedat}%
    \printfield{eventtitle}%
  }%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
  {}
  {\setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{%
      \printfield{venue}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printeventdate}}%
  \newunit
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%
  {Établit\space par}%
  {dir\adddotspace\smartof},
  in = {\textit{in}},%                                    %et en italique
  editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
  editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
  opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
  idem = {\emph{idem}},%
  byeditor = {dir\adddot},% Remplace sous la direction de pour les improceedings etc.
  ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
  %pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
  %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}

%modifie les pages des articles ... par pp. au lieu de p.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%

%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
  {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
    {\bibnamedash}
    {\printnames{editor}%
      %   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
      \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
      \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
    %     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
    \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
    \clearname{editor}}
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

% put (dir.) at the end (byeditor)  pour tout ce qui est in : auteur dir.
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
  {}
  {%%%\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}       %%%% suppress
    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    % \addspace                                  %%%% suppress
    %     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}          %%%%
    \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}             %%%%
    \clearname{editor}%            %%%%%%%%%
    \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

%%modifié book pour virgule
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
  {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}}
  {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
  {\printfield{isbn}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%     rajoute a la fin series + nomber pour avoir la collection a la fin de la ligne. La modification du style est plus bas.
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

%Change ordre des entrées pour les in quelquechoses :
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
  {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}}
  {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
  {\printfield{isbn}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
  {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}}
  {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
  {\printfield{isbn}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  %  \newunit\newblock %%%% enlever
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
  {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}}
  {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
  {\printfield{isbn}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{proceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
  {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}}
  {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
  {\printfield{isbn}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}% rajoute collection
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

%% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
  {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
    {\bibnamedash}
    {\printnames{author}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
      \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
      \ifnameundef{namea}
      {}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printnames{namea}}}}
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{nameatype}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother

%met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
  {}
  {\printtext[parens]{%
      \printtext{}%
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit*{\space}%
      \printfield{number}%
      \printtext{}}%
  }} %%% il y a un point en enleveant \nopunct.

%Rajoute une virgule après le titre du journal et avant le numéro du volume
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
  {}
  {\newunit
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

%Permet d'enlever le tiret après in si pas d'auteur.
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
    \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}

%permet de mettre les initiales entre parenthèses et surtout les particules nobilaires
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
  {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
    \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
    \ifblank{#3}{}{%
      \ifcapital
      {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
      {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
      \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
    \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
    \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
    \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibparens{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}\isdot}}% added \mkbibparens
  {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
    \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
    \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
    \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
    \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
    \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}% added \bibopenparen
    \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}% added \ifblank{#2}{\bibopenparen}{}
    \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\bibcloseparen}}}% this line is new

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{arnaud2005, arcelin1976}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works but the citation style is still in small caps. And after initial I don't want a space before the bracket.

And I don't understand the difference between biber and bibtex...

Comment: As far as I could tell, the image my code produced matched the target image in the question. If there's a mismatch, I'm afraid that it is too subtle for my eye!

Comment: Biber means you run `biber` to generate the bibliography and citations rather than `bibtex`. I.e. `latex` (or `pdflatex` or `xelatex` or `lualatex`) -> `biber` -> `latex` (-> `latex` if required) as opposed to `latex` -> `bibtex` -> `latex` -> `latex`.

Comment: Tanks for the explanation of difference.
And for subtle difference is that I have a space after initial:
I have:         (P. ) ...
I would like: (P.) 
I hope that I'm  understandable

Comment: OK. I see. I'm guessing you didn't write this code but I can't find an attribution in it. Is the source another answer here or somewhere else? Do you know who wrote it?

Comment: @Axelito I can get rid of the space, but I am not sure how to correctly update the code as I don't know what change makes it necessary. I've pinged moewe from your question with a query about this.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OVV5c.png

Comment: Like always for me, it's moewe's code: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165189/same-parenthesis-for-nameprefix-and-first-initial

Comment: @Axelito Me, too. Very often, anyways ;).