# Biblatex - How to add parentheses around author first name?

Tags: biblatex, brackets, author

For my memoir, I'm asked to use a specific style for my references. For example, for this entry (the most basic one)

```
  @book{huanMarineSovietique2002a,
  title = {La marine soviétique},
  author = {Huan, Claude},
  date = {2002},
  publisher = {Marines Editions},
  langid = {french},
```

I should have something looking like this

> HUAN (Claude), *The soviet navy*, Marines Editions, 2002.

I'm using the `verbose-trad3` style with a few changes already (found them online), but I have no idea how to put the first name of the author between parentheses and the family name first.

My header for references is looking like this for the moment:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=verbose-trad3]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio_memoire.bib}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{, }
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{in = {dans}}
\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

Which gives me this:

> Claude HUAN, *The soviet navy*, Marines Editions, 2002.

So the author name is my last problem, I can't find how to deal with the first name and the last name separately.

I tried the solution suggested here [How to reverse name and first name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151820/how-to-reverse-name-and-first-name) but the result is adding commas between the two parts …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modifying alphabetic biblabels with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155812/35864) and [Same parenthesis for nameprefix and first initial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165189/35864) are related, but were written for older `biblatex` versions.

If you only need to wrap the given name in round brackets, I suggest you first change the name format to `family-given`, you can then remove the comma between family and given name by redefining `\revsdnamepunct`, finally we wrap the given name in parentheses by setting `\mkbibnamegiven`.

We also redefine the bibmacro responsible for full citations and tell it not to change the name format.

Note that I changed from `citestyle=verbose-trad3`, which is equivalent to `bibname=numeric, citestyle=verbose-trad3,` to the more homogeneous `style=verbose-trad3,`. In particular the numbers generated in the bibliography with only `citestyle=verbose-trad3` did not correspond to anything else in your document.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad3]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{\addcomma\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{in = {dans}}

\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Sigfridsson (Emma) et Ryde (Ulf)" family names in small caps]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think I'm starting to understand how this is supposed to work